# Mask element\Attribute value, using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a xml string that has certain values that I want to mask. I also have a blacklist List that contains names of elements or attributes that I want to mask. How can I do this using Linq?

```
var BlackList=new List<string>{"ssn", "dateofbirth"};

var xml=@"<Rows><Row><SSN>123-12-1234</SSN><Address>123 Somewhere Street</Address><DateOfBirth>12-12-2012</DateOfBirth></Row><Row><SSN value=""123-12-1234""/><Address value=""123 Somewhere Street""/><DateOfBirth value=""12-12-2012""/></Row></Rows>";
```

The resultset would look like this:

```
"<Rows><Row><SSN>RemovedForSecurity</SSN><Address>123 Somewhere Street</Address><DateOfBirth>RemovedForSecurity</DateOfBirth></Row><Row><SSN value="RemovedForSecurity"/><Address value="123 Somewhere Street"/><DateOfBirth value="RemovedForSecurity"/></Row></Rows>"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well to start with, use LINQ to XML for all the actual XML. The fact that you've started with a string and ended up with a string is incidental: you're really trying to manipulate an XML document. At that point it's reasonably easy:

```
var redactedElements = new HashSet<XName>
{
    "SSN",
    "CreditCard"
};
var redactedAttributes = new HashSet<XName>
{
    "dateofbirth",
    ...
};

var elements = doc.Descendants()
                  .Where(x => redactedElements.Contains(x.Name))
                  .ToList();
foreach (var element in elements)
{
    element.Value = "RemovedForSecurity";
}

var attributes = doc.Descendants()
                    .Attributes()
                    .Where(x => redactedAttributes.Contains(x.Name))
                    .ToList();
foreach (var attribute in attributes)
{
    attribute.Value = "RemovedForSecurity";
}
```

EDIT: To be case-insensitive, you'd keep a case-insensitive list of local names:

```
var redactedElements = new HashSet<string>(StringEqualityComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
{
    "SSN",
    "CreditCard"
};
var elements = doc.Descendants()
                  .Where(x => redactedElements.Contains(x.Name.LocalName))
                  .ToList();
// Ditto for the attributes
```

It would be better if you specified the exact names though, IMO.

Comment: I love the usage of the HashSet, most people would have just created a List/Collection. :)

Comment: We will need to change "x.name" to "n.Name.LocalName.ToLower()" in the code above. Thanks @lazyberezovsky.

Comment: @AjitGoel: No, you won't - because the set is a set of `XName` values. At least, you won't unless you don't know the exact `XName` - if you want to do it case-insensitively, you'd have to go to the local name and ideally use a case insensitive comparison instead of using `ToLower`, but if you *do* know the exact names (as I'd expect) it's better to use the set approach.

Comment: I guess I need a code example to understand better(I am sorry). The xmlstring might have a "SSN" or an "ssn" that would need to be compared against the blacklist. The blacklist has only lowercase xnames that the xml string need to be compared against.

Comment: @AjitGoel: So you really don't know what case the XML elements will be? That's very strange, to be honest. Do you *genuinely* not know them, or is it just that you'd prefer not to be specific?

Comment: @AjitGoel: I've edited my answer to give you a case-insensitive approach too.

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet. I am writing a soapextension that will log both requests and responses if there is an error. This passthrough soapextension would  work against 1000's of webservices each having the request\response data in different formats including "encoded strings". I need to make sure that before I log the data I remove all possible "Personal identifiable information". This is the reason I need the blackList or the string comparison to be case insensitive.

Comment: @AjitGoel: Hmm - if you're working against thousands of different web services, I think you're on a hiding to nothing - goodness knows how some of them might encode PII. In particular, rather than just "Address" you're need "SubscriberAddress", "CustomerAddress", "CustAddress" etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
var unsecureElements = 
    XElement.Parse(xml)
            .Descendants()
            .Where(n => blackList.Contains(n.Name.LocalName.ToLower()));

foreach (var element in unsecureElements)
{
    var valueAttribute = element.Attribute("value");

    if (valueAttribute != null) // check if unsecure element has value attribute
        valueAttribute.SetValue("RemovedForSecurity");
    else
        element.Value = "RemovedForSecurity";
}
```